# How do I implement per-app routing behavior on windows?

Tags: windows, networking, routes, vpn, wfp

I am running a VPN in windows 10 desktop (using OpenVPN) and the VPN is the default gateway, so that all traffic by default goes through the VPN tunnel.

However, I would like to exempt certain apps from the VPN, so that their traffic goes directly out the physical interface instead, by passing the VPN (so-called "split tunnelling")

I assume this solution would involve the WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) API, and perhaps the Windows equivalent of

```
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_BINDTODEVICE, device, sizeof(device))
```

I have this working in Linux currently via "cgroups" and policy-based routing/multiple routing tables.

But it is my understanding that Windows has neither policy based routing or multiple routing tables. But i can still think of a way of achieving this in Windows, but I cannot find the APIs to make it happen

One way is to hook the socket creation of a specific app and then use the windows equivalent of `SO_BINDTO_DEVICE` socket option (`setsockopt()`) to force the socket to be bound to the physical interface rather than the tap driver.

But, again, I cannot find the relevant APIs to make the above happen.

So I have a few questions:

(1) Is what i want to do possible within the given APIs of WFP (Windows Filtering Platform) or Windows APIs in genral? if so, which APIs do you advise i look at?

(2) Or, must i write a "WFP call-out driver" ? If so, would you be able to point me towards some resources for this, and possibility a good starting point for my particular problem? :)

(3) Is there anything else I might be missing? a simpler approach to achieve what i want? I know that it is possible in windows, as i have see the feature in some VPNs, but i would like to replicate it in my own personal VPN  :)

Comment: For the person who voted this as off-topic....WFP *is* a programming API, any solution to this problem would be a solution written in code, using programming APIs. Note i specifically ask for "API" information. I don't know how you can say this isn't related to programming....if it is, then 50% of questions on this forum are also off-topic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can force an app to use your VPN connection by copying and editing your (Windows) VPN connection.

1. Open the run prompt with: `WIN+R`
2. Type: **`ncpa.cpl`**
3. Copy your "old VPN" to `APP_VPN` (for example)
4. Open a *Normal* user Powershell
5. Change the new VPN connection with:

```
Add-VpnConnectionTriggerApplication -Name "APP_VPN" –ApplicationID "C:\path-to-your\game.exe" -Force

# Enable (Application) split-tunneling
Set-VpnConnection -Name "APP_VPN" -SplitTunneling $True
```

You can also check the VPN settings details in the *phonebook* in:
`C:\Users\<User>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Network\Connections\Pbk`

Done!